# Ideal generated by 3 and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is not a principal ideal in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

> Show that the ideal generated by 3 and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is not a principal ideal in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

I fail to understand how can 3 and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ generate an ideal.

$$(3,1+\sqrt{-5}) = (a+b\sqrt{-5}) \quad (1)$$

I think the proof would start like so:

It follows from $(1)$ that
$$3 = (a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})$$

But I have no clue why...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to show that your equation (1) cannot hold, i.e., that $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal. If equation (1) holds, then since $3\in (3,1+\sqrt{-5}) = (a+b\sqrt{-5})$, it must be the case that $3$ is a multiple of $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ (since that is what the ideal $(a+b\sqrt{-5})$ consists of), so that there must be some $c+d\sqrt{-5}$ such that $3 = (a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: What am I missing here?  How can we have $1 + \sqrt{-5} \in Z[\sqrt 5]$?

Comment: @rogerl, I understand your explanation. However, I am a little confused by the notation $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ and what it implies for the ideal...

Comment: @RobertLewis, that was a typo. It should be corrected in my original question.

Comment: @JustinD. Recall that the notation $(a,b)$ for an ideal of the ring $R$, and $(a)$ for a principal ideal, mean $(a,b)=\{ar+bs:r,s\in R\}$ and $(a)=\{ar:r\in R\}$. Thus it is always true that $a\in(a)$ and $a\in(a,b)$.

Comment: @Alan Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a PID is not the same as showing that $(3, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ is not principal.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, so $(3,1+\sqrt{-5}) = \{3 + (1+\sqrt{-5})(\sqrt{-5}) \}$ in $Z[\sqrt{-5}]$? That does not make sense...

Comment: @JustinD $(3,1+\sqrt{-5}) = \{3(c+d\sqrt{-5}) + (1+\sqrt{-5})(e+f\sqrt{-5})\,\mid\, c, d, e, f\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is just what $Z[\sqrt 5]$ *is*?  I thought it was all $a + b\sqrt 5$ with $a, b \in Z$.

Comment: @JustinD. Rather, $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})=\{3(a+b\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5}):a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z\}$, where I have also applied the definition $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-5}:a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: Oh I see now. $r, s \in R$. I am still not used to working with $R$ as a ring. I always confuse it with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JustinD. Do you know how to proceed, given $3=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: @JustinD Remember how, in the integers, if $d = \gcd(a,b)$ then we can find $r, s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ar+bs = d$, and that in fact for any choice of integers $r, s$ we get $ar+bs$ being some multiple of $d$? So $\{ar+bs\}$ is the set of all multiples of $d$, which is just $(d)$, the ideal generated by $d$. The idea here is exactly the same, except that the ideal you get is not the set of multiples of any single element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ (of course, that's what you're trying to prove).

Comment: @ Justin D.:   a typo?  Praise what gods there be!  My faith in algebra, number theory, and humanity have all been simultaneously restored!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A usual procedure to treat this kind of questions is to consider a "norm" on these rings. For $z=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ define $N(z)=z(a-b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2\in\mathbb Z$. Then $N(zw)=N(z)N(w)$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, which implies in particular that $z$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ iff $N(z)=1$.

Suppose that $I=\langle3,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$, the ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ generated by $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$, is principal, say $I=\langle z\rangle$, with $z=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. The elements $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ obviously belong to $I$, so they are multiples **in** $\boldsymbol{\pmb{\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-5}]}$ of the generator $z$. Therefore we have that $N(z)$ divides both $N(3)=9$ and $N(1+\sqrt{-5})=6$ **in** $\pmb{\mathbb Z}$, and so $N(z)$ divides $9-6=3$. In other words, $a^2+5b^2=1$ or $3$, so necessarily $b=0$ (otherwise $a^2+5b^2\geq5$), which in turn implies $a^2=1$ (because $3$ is not a square in $\mathbb Z$), so $z=\pm1$, and in particular $\pm z\in I$, so $1\in I$.

Thus, we can write $1=3(c+d\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})(e+f\sqrt{-5})$, with $c,d,e,f\in\mathbb Z$, which implies $1=3c+e-5f$ and $0=3d+e+f$. Taking classes modulo $3$ we obtain $1=e+f$ and $0=e+f$, which is impossible. This contradiction shows the result.

Comment: I think it’s quite clear at the end of your second paragraph already that $1\notin (3,1+\sqrt{-5})$, because one sees by direct computation that $(3)=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$, and if either of these factors were equal to $(1)$, the other would be equal to $(3)$, which it isn’t. I do like your explanation better than my own, because it doesn’t depend on that (definitely nonelementary) theorem I used.

Answer (score 8):

It’s a theorem in algebraic number theory that if $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field $K$ and $z\in R$, then the field-theoretic norm of $z$ is equal to the cardinality of $R/(z)$. Here, $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5}\,)$ and $R$ is the $\mathbb Z$-span of $\{1,\sqrt{-5}\,\}$, i.e. $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}\,]$. Since $R/(3)$ has cardinality $9$, the larger ideal $(3,1+\sqrt{-5}\,)=I$ has the property that $R/I$ has cardinality $3$. But the norm of $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is $a^2+5b^2$. This never takes the value $3$, that is, there is no $z$ of norm $3$, so the ideal is not principal.

Comment: @ Lubin:  fascinating, +1!  Where can I go to see a proof of this?

Comment: @ Lubin:  that is to say, proofs of the results you use?

Comment: @ Lubin:  oh, I see, algebraic number theory . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis, for these things, I depend on the book “Algebraic Theory of Numbers”, by P. Samuel. The theorem I quoted is Proposition 1 of Section 3.5, it’s page 52 in my edition.

Comment: @ Lubin:  thanks so much, I'll try and check it out.   By the way, do you know any good (hopefully *free*) online sourxes for this stuff.  Thanks.again!

Comment: It is of course good to know that this is the one standard technique one always uses to try and show some ideal of a number ring is not principal. Without this, the calculation of the class group would be much more annoying. Also, proving that $\|(a)\|=|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)|$ is slightly more difficult than one might assume. Generally one can actually prove that $\|I\|=\|N_{L/K}(I)\|$, where here $N_{L/K}$ denotes the ideal norm. Then, we could recover this fact from the fact (also annoying) that $N_{L/K}((a))=(N_{L/K}(a))$ and the fact that $\|(a)\|=|a|$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ (obvious).